# IntelliJ 13 not picking up build.sbt changes

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, dependencies, sbt

I'm using IntelliJ 13.1.2 on OS-X Mavericks.
I added a new dependency to my `build.sbt` inside an IntelliJ project. I synced my project as well as my build.sbt but I cannot import classes from this new library in my Scala classes.

However, when I do a `sbt clean complile; sbt console` on a terminal (outside of IntelliJ) I can successfully import classes from this new library.

Can anyone help me resolve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Usually when you change the SBT file a message appears asking you if you want to refresh the imports does this not happen to you?Alternatively you can set SBT to do it automatically into preferences -> SBT -> use auto import.

Comment: I don't see that error message. and I don't see the "use auto import" option when I go to "preferences -> SBT -> Use auto import"

Comment: this is the plugin I'm using. https://github.com/orfjackal/idea-sbt-plugin/wiki (Version 1.5.1)

Comment: @SoumyaSimanta it has nothing to do with *automatic* picking of changes -- you have to be happy with stock IntelliJ *scala* plugin, which understands sbt project files since 13.x IDEA release (don't remember exact version)

Comment: @om-nom-nom - so should I uninstall/disable the sbt plugin ?

Comment: @SoumyaSimanta you should not, what I am saying is that mentioned sbt plugin has nothing more to propagating dependency changes to IDEA than, say, jenkins or JSP plugins (in other words, nothing) -- it's just a terminal shortcut. The relevant plugins are: 1) in pre-13.x era [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) which has to be invoked manually every time you made changes to project description 2) currently, ordinary *scala* plugin, supplied by JetBrains is capable of tracking all changes and exporting them back to IDEA, in automatic fashion (by-default, via popup, but anyways)

Comment: So, do you have [scala plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=1347) installed? Is it [fresh enough](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2013/11/18/built-in-sbt-support-in-intellij-idea-13/)?

Comment: I've Version: 0.36.431 of [this plugin](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/SCA/Scala+Plugin+for+IntelliJ+IDEA)

Comment: Can you please elaborate, do you have one or more projects you're trying to get working? How does your `build.sbt` looks like. If you have more than one project, are they built by the same build.sbt? Does the build work from console?

Comment: I just have one project and yes it works correctly from the console.

Answer (score 2):

In preferences -> SBT (in Project Settings section) -> check the box next to 'Use auto-import' and that should keep IDEA synced with your build.sbt